# GridView with ListActivity

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I'm trying to make a GridView work in place of a Listview. The code uses a ListActivity, here it is below:

```
public class BorrowerList extends ListActivity implements
LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private static final int ACTIVITY_PERSON_UPCLOSE = 3;

private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

// -----------------------------------------------------------

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.grid_view_person_record);
    this.getListView().setDividerHeight(2);
    fillData();
}



// -----------------------------------------------------------



private void fillData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] from = new String[] { BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_NAME };     

    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.pername};

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_view_rowitem, null, from,
            to, 0);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

// -----------------------------------------------------------


@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();
    //fillData();
}


// -----------------------------------------------------------


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    // Remove to show all records
    //String mSelection = BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_NAME + "=?"; // SQL request
    //String[] selectionArgs = {"Jack Reacher"}; // The actual argument

    BorrowMeContentProvider.distinctSwitch = true;


    String[] projection = { BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_ID, BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_NAME };


    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
        BorrowMeContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);


    return cursorLoader;
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    adapter.swapCursor(arg1);


}

// -----------------------------------------------------------

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    adapter.swapCursor(null);

}

// -----------------------------------------------------------

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    // When Clicked - loads record ID and sends it to PersonRecord class

    Intent i = new Intent(this, PersonRecord.class);

    // Sends a URI request to the content provider saying we are looking for a
    // particular record
    Uri borrowUri = Uri.parse(BorrowMeContentProvider.CONTENT_URI + "/" + id);
    i.putExtra(BorrowMeContentProvider.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, borrowUri);

    // Activity returns an result if called with startActivityForResult
    // startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_PERSON_UPCLOSE);

    // Removed the for Result as it would not allow the previous activity
    // to release, so it would live people on the list even if all records had been deleted

    startActivity(i);

}

}
```

I ask a previous question on the stackoverflow and I got a simple "Replace ListView with GridView - which could be entirely correct - but I haven't quite got it yet.

Here is the error message I get:

```
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fthatnoise.borrow.me/com.fthatnoise.borrow.me.BorrowerList}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.widget.GridView
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.widget.GridView
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at com.fthatnoise.borrow.me.BorrowerList.onCreate(BorrowerList.java:39)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     ... 11 more
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     ... 24 more
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x3
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3340)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:431)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.widget.AdapterView.<init>(AdapterView.java:235)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:766)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.widget.GridView.<init>(GridView.java:110)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.widget.GridView.<init>(GridView.java:106)
09-15 18:30:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     ... 27 more
```

Any help you be great. Thanks!

This is the layout containing the GridView (R.layout.grid_view_person_record):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    tools:context=".PersonRecord" >

     <GridView
         android:id="@android:id/list"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:columnWidth="80dp"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:numColumns="auto_fit"
         android:paddingLeft="@android:id/list"
         android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

    </GridView>

     <TextView
         android:id="@android:id/empty"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/list"
         android:layout_alignTop="@android:id/list" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show the XML file R.layout.grid_view_person_record`

Comment: @Erik I have added it now.

Comment: Can you move the `fillData();` from `onCreate()` to `onResume()`. Look at [this](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/)

Comment: Would that help with GridView?